# wget a raw file from Github from a private repo

Tags: linux, git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, github

I am trying to get a raw file from github ***private project*** using wget. Usually if my project is public it is very simple

> For Public Repo This is my repo url (you don't have to click on it to answer this question)

https://github.com/samirtendulkar/profile_rest_api/blob/master/deploy/server_setup.sh

I click raw
[image]

After I lick raw My URL looks like this

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samirtendulkar/profile_rest_api/master/deploy/server_setup.sh (Notice only the word "*raw*" is added to the URL)

which is awesome I then do

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-47:~$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samirtendulkar/profile_rest_api/master/deploy/server_setup.sh
```

when I do `ls` it shows that the file has been downloaded

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-47:~$ ls
'server_setup.sh'
```

> For a Private repo The raw file comes with a token

https://github.com/samirtendulkar/my_project/blob/master/deploy/server_setup.sh

So far so good Now when I click Raw (see image above) My URL changes and has a token in it along with the "*raw*" prefix

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samirtendulkar/my_project/master/deploy/server_setup.sh?token=AkSv7SycSHacUNlSEZamo6hpMAI6ZhsLks5b4uFuwA%3D%3D

The url has these extra parameters `?token=AkSv7SycSHacUNlSEZamo6hpMAI6ZhsLks5b4uFuwA%3D%3D`

My wget does not work. How Do I fix this issue. By the way when I say it does not work I mean instead of the `ls` showing

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-47:~$ ls
    'server_setup.sh'
```

It shows as below

[image]
which is not making me run futher commands like

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-47:~$ chmod +x server_setup.sh
```

and

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-47:~$ sudo ./server_setup.sh
```

which I need to get the project on to AWS
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how your wget does not work? If you provide the error message or actual outcome, it should help solve your problem. From my experience, getting a URL with such parameters with wget can work, but you might need single quotes around the URL.

Comment: @joanis updated question with the errors

Comment: Never put images of text in your question. Put the text in.

Comment: If you're just downloading one file, I would use wget's -O option: `wget -O server_setup.sh URL`.

Comment: Replace your wget command with “wget http://url -o server-setup.sh”. It will download the file as server-setup.sh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use wget's `-O` option when you're downloading just one file at a time:

```
wget -O server_setup.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samirtendulkar/my_project/master/deploy/server_setup.sh?token=AkSv7SycSHacUNlSEZamo6hpMAI6ZhsLks5b4uFuwA%3D%3D
```

The downside is that you have to know the output file name, but I think that's OK if I understand your question well.

Answer (score 14):

The token is from the Personal Access Tokens section that you can find the details in [Github](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).

With Personal Access Tokens, you can create one and pick the first option "repo" to get access control over the private repos for the token.

Following line solved my problem which was not being able to download the file.

Hope this will help

```bash
wget --header 'Authorization: token PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/repoOwner/repoName/master/folder/filename
```